# How to delete an entity then wait for the entity to be removed before proceeding

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to delete an entity and wait for the entity to be removed before proceeding to my query.  This code below deletes the entity but doesn't wait, what am I doing wrong?

**Function #1**

```
data = ndb.Key(Invoices, int(identifier))
f = data.delete_async()
f.wait()
```

**Function #2**

```
data = Invoices.query()
template_values = {'data':data}
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/income.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

I want the `f.wait()` to wait till the entity is deleted before proceeding to my query.  I have tried using a `time.sleep( 0.5 )`, and works but is not what I want to do.

Comment: You are runing into eventual consistancy, if you are performing a non ancestor query to see if the entity still remains.  Read up on eventual consistancy. If you want to check the entity has really been deleted, `get` it by the key.

Comment: I have tried the 'get()' that you suggested, but it returns 'None'.  And when I do my query thereafter it still shows the deleted entity.  But if I refresh my page (redo the query) it disappears.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are runing into eventual consistancy, if you are performing a non ancestor query to see if the entity still remains. Read up on eventual consistancy. If you want to check the entity has really been deleted, get it by the key.

You said

> I have tried the 'get()' that you suggested, but it returns 'None'.
>   And when I do my query thereafter it still shows the deleted entity.
>   But if I refresh my page (redo the query) it disappears.

This is correct and expected behavior and is a manifestation of eventual consistency.

You need to

1. Understand what eventual consistency means
2. Restructure your app to suit this behavior

And you REALLY REALLY need to read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying to make sense of the ancestor / parent thing for AGES! and have finally got it working in my app.  I found the example from the 'structuring_for_strong_consistency' document uses the example from the Python Tutorial >> Using the Datastore document, the full example helped me a lot.  Once again thanks!

Comment: I also really needed to read the link you posted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`delete_async()` is the asynchronous version of [`delete()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#delete).

If you want to delete the item and wait for the operation to complete, just use `delete()`:

```
data = ...
data.delete()
```

If you have things you can do after the deletion starts, but later need to know it has finished, you can use `delete_async()` and then use `get_result()` on the returned object to wait for the call to complete, as per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#delete_async):

> This function is identical to delete() except that it returns an
>   asynchronous object. You can call get_result() on the return value to
>   block on the call.

```
data = ...
f = data.delete_async()
...
f.get_result()
```

Note that if you are not doing anything between the `delete_async()` call and the `get_result()` call, there is no value in using `delete_async()`, use `delete()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have tried the delete() on its own.  When I make a query strait after that the entity is deleted, it's still there.  It works properly if I add a sleep timer after the delete.  But that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I know it has to do with the consistency of the datastore having a slight delay before the updates entities reflect properly.